# The project doesn't find the jsp files, in include tag

Tags: java, eclipse, jsp, tomcat8

I'm doing a college project, using MVC in java web. I'm using the eclipse photon ide, tomcat v8.0 and postgresql. 
The problem is that I created a folder called "include", and inside this, I've put 3 files, "head.jsp" "navbar.jsp" and "scripts.jsp".
Until some days ago, this was running normaly, but I've create some Controllers (they doesn't affect the jsp include files), and now my include isn't working!

This the error of the inicial page:

[My "index" page](https://i.stack.imgur.com/J7cS0.png)

["menuInicial.jsp" file](https://i.stack.imgur.com/XG21e.png)

["head.jsp" file](https://i.stack.imgur.com/hBALD.png)

[The folder strcut](https://i.stack.imgur.com/m1EBl.png)

Comment: The relevant code and information must be posted, **as text**, in the question itself. Not as links to images.

Comment: Ok, I'll change that, thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`menuInicial.jsp` file is already in the `view` folder. Try,

```
<%@include file="include/head.jsp"%>
```

Comment: That worked!! A fool mistake haha thank you!!

Comment: @GuilhermeMello U r welcome! don't forget to accept the answer.

Comment: Sorry, I'm newbie here haha, done!